# Scoping issue with a helper method to manipulate a string

Tags: c++, string, scope

I want to use a helper method to perform an operation on a string. I would like the method to have two parameters: input and output. I think there is a scoping problem with how I want to solve the problem because when I try to display the output, it is blank. I've minimized my code so you can see the approach I am taking.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void example_method(string in, string out);

int main(){
    string input;
    string output;
    cin >> input;
    example_method(input, output);
    cout << "The result is: " << output << endl;
    return 0;
}

void example_method(string in, string out){
    out = in;
}
```

This minimization compiles and runs, but no matter what string I enter, the result is always blank.
What would be a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the output variable to the function, which means a copy of it is being pushed onto the stack, and then the stack variable is being altered and never returned back to the original variable.  What you want to do is pass a reference to the variable, Like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void example_method(string in, string &out);

int main() {
    string input = "";
    string output = "";
    cin >> input;
    example_method(input, output);
    cout << "The result is: " << output << endl;
    return 0;
}

void example_method(string in, string &out) {
    out = in;
}
```

Comment: How would I assign the value instead of a reference?

Comment: -1: Output is uninitialized, and a reference would be preferable. This is bad example code to give to a starting C++ programmer.

Comment: The description I gave is accurate.  The code is not perfect, I was trying to help without being at my dev station.  I've updated the code.

Comment: @Sjoerd is a reference preferable with a variable size data type like a string?

Comment: @Dave Variable size has nothing to do with it, why do you think that would make a difference? Whatever the type, a reference is easier as it doesn't require an introduction to 'new', 'delete' or 'memory leak'.

Comment: Good call @Sjoerd I've updated the answer with full working example using reference rather than pointer which is indeed the proper way for this.

Comment: Did this answer your question @Iatesometau ?  If so, pls accept and mark complete.  Otherwise LMK if there's something else I can help with.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution One:** The string `output` will always be blank, with your code in its present form. This is because `output` is only being copied to another string instance when it is passed as an argument to `example_method`. `out` is the other string instance which takes the value of `output`. In other words what this means is that `string out=output` and nothing else. The code line `out = in;` only copies the value of `in` to `out`.

`So, actually the value of output is not being acted upon at all`.

In order to effect the value of `output` you have to pass its value `by reference` or in other words, you have to pass the `address of output` to example_method and that address is to be taken by a pointer. **This way what ever changes are made via the pointer also effect the value of the output string outside the scope of the example_method**.

The following code segment illustrates my point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void example_method(string another_string, string *pointer_to_output);

int main()
{
string input="I am a test string";
string output="";
//cout<<"Enter input string"<<endl;
//cin>>input;   
example_method(input,&output);
cout<<"The result is: "<<output<<endl;
return 0;
}

void example_method(string another_string, string *pointer_to_output) 
{
*pointer_to_output=another_string;
}
```

**Solution two:**
Why not simply change the `return type` of the `example_method` from `void` to `std::string`? By this approach `void example_method(string in, string out);` changes to `string example_method(string in, string out);` in the declaration above the main.
And the returned output string is put out on the screen using `cout<<example_method(input, output);`
This way you can simply return your output to the screen using `cout`.

This way your code works, it achieves what you are trying to do and there is no real need of using pointers.

**THE MODIFIED CODE**:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string example_method(string in, string out);

int main(){
string input;
string output;
cin >> input;
cout<<example_method(input, output);
// cout << "The result is: " << output << endl;
return 0;
}

string example_method(string in, string out){
out = in;
return out;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a argument to a function, the value is copied into the parameter.

In your case, the function will operate on the copied value, and leave the original value untouched (in this case: empty).

This can be changed by declaring the parameter as a 'reference parameter'. This is done by adding a `&` to the type, like this: `string& out`. Then no local copy will be made, so the original value will be updated.

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void example_method(std::string in, std::string& out); // note the additional &

int main(){
    std::string input;
    std::string output;
    std::cin >> input;
    example_method(input, output);
    std::cout << "The result is: " << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void example_method(std::string in, std::string& out){ // Note the additional &
    out = in;
}
```

---

A different approach is to specify a return value for the function.

Your function is returning nothing (`void`), so you could return the resulting string instead. In that case, the output parameter is no longer required, but you'll have to assign the returned value to the `output` variable at the calling site.

A complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string example_method(std::string in); // note that 'output' is gone

int main(){
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::string output = example_method(input);
    std::cout << "The result is: " << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

std::string example_method(std::string in){
    return in; // use 'return' to return a value.
}
```